# Is it possible to connect MQTT client to RabbitMQ having Node.JS as intermediate gateway?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, mqtt

This is what I want to do:

I want to connect my client using `MQTT` to `Node.JS server` and then from there(Node.JS Server) I want to handle all pub/sub. When client publishes any message, it will go to `Node.JS server` and from there it will be sent to `RabbitMQ` and reverse for the subscriber.

Flow is like :-

> MQTT -> Node.JS -> RabbitMQ.

***Edit:***

**Server.Js**

```
var mosca = require('mosca')
var pubsubsettings = {
    type: 'mqtt',
    json: false,
    mqtt: require('mqtt'),
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1883
};
var settings = {
    port: 1883,
    backend: pubsubsettings  
};

var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);


function setup() {
    console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}


server.on('clientConnected', function (client) {
    console.log('client connected', client.id);
});


server.on('published', function (packet, client) {
    console.log('Published : ', packet.payload);
});


server.on('subscribed', function (topic, client) {
    console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('unsubscribed', function (topic, client) {
    console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

server.on('clientDisconnecting', function (client) {
    console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});


server.on('clientDisconnected', function (client) {
    console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});
```

This is what i found on `mosca` home page. I added few lines for `RabbitMQ` connections.

Now I want to create a client that can connect to this `Node.JS` server. But I am not able to figure out the way to connect.

Comment: It's probably possible, yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @robertklep - I have created one Mosca server which communicates with RabbitMQ but I am not able to find out the way to connect to that mosca server by mqtt client.

Comment: What client are you using and how is it trying to connect to Mosqa? [`mqtt-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-cli) seems to work just fine using a Mosca broker.

Comment: @robertklep : I am trying to use `mqtt.js` client side.

Comment: Perhaps add some more context to your question, because it's working just fine for me. For instance, how exactly are you connecting to Mosca from `mqtt.js`? What configuration are you starting Mosca with? Are you getting errors, and if so, what are they? Etc.

Comment: @robertklep: I have updated question. May be this could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different possibilities, just to figure out two of them:

a) are you trying this one?

MQTT Client A -> Node.js/mosca Broker 1 bridged -> RabbitMQ Broker 2

b) why not this one?

Both Clients can exchange messages by publishing and subscribing to the same topics in the Broker

MQTT Client A <-> RabbitMQ Broker 1 <-> Node.js/MQTT.js Client B

For implementing MQTT clients take a look at:
https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/libraries

Comment: Thanks for your response, I found solution according to my question,. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just achieved the same. Hope the answer helps

```
var mosca = require("mosca");
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var pubsubsettings = {
    type: 'mqtt',
    json: false,
    mqtt: require('mqtt'),
    clientId: 'MqttBrokerPublisher',
    username: '<USERNAME>',
    password: '<PASSWORD>',
    host: '<YOUR_HOST>',
    port: 1883,
};

var moscaSettings = {
    //port: 1883,
    backend: pubsubsettings,
    http: {
        port: 3000,
        bundle: true,
        static: './'
    }
}


var server = new mosca.Server(moscaSettings);

server.on('ready', function(){
    console.log('connected to the server');
});

server.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connected to the server');
});

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published', packet.payload);
});

server.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('error', err);
});
```

**Explaination:**

In the above code i am using hybrid mobile app as MQTT client (*Cordova App*) which talks only via websocket using [mqtt.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js)

> At the time of writing this post there was no cordova plugin the
>   supported **iOS**. **Android only** plugin is available. Follow this
>   [link](https://github.com/arcoirislabs/cordova-plugin-mqtt)

So i resorted on websocket implementation of **Mqtt.js** which supports both **iOS (9.3+) and Android(4.4.4+)/Cross-walk** running on cordova webview/browser

Here [Mosca](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) is used as **Node.js** Pub/Sub http server gateway which connects to my **Mosquitto-RabbitMQ** backend. Finally my mobile App talks to mosca which in turn talks to Mosquitto.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I solved it long ago. Even It was my self only who contributed on mosca for this example. check this link. https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/commit/7a60e496a6c80a33d2c77a1be809ea0dca59c126

Comment: @Pritam thats cool. But documentation is not updated on this. I struggled a lot to get the answer.

Comment: Yes. Document is still not updated. You can update it and send the Author PR about the update. Feel free to update. It is open source. ;)